# Passing a variable as a parameter to a class and changing that value of that variable in method within that class

Tags: c#, timer

forgive me if there's any typos i wrote this by hand.. i was just wondering if there's anyway i can pass a parameter to a class and change it's variable within a method of that variable.

i was thinking of passing by reference but i can't pass the variable through the Elapsed method property.. any suggestions?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private CustomTimerClass _customTimer;
  private int _varIWantToChange;

  public MainWindow()
  {
     _varIWantToChange = 1;
     _customTimer = new CustomTimerClass(_varIWantToChange);
  }
  ...
}

public CustomTimerClass()
{
  private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

  public CustomTimerClass(int varIWantToChange)
  {
    _timer = new Timer();
    ...
    _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;  //i can't pass varIwantToChange as a parameter here
  }

  public void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    //i want to be able to change the value of the variable "_varIWantToChange" here
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? What's the purpose of mutating the `int`?

Comment: i want to be able to pass a variable into my timer class, and when the timer elapses, be able to change the value of that variable

Comment: Why? I think we have a case of XY problem right now -- you're asking a question for how to solve a sub-problem of the solution you've come up with to solve a larger problem, but there might be a better solution to your actual problem.

Comment: @Daniel Mann this is a very broken down problem of something i want to do in a real project... in actuality i'm trying to pass in an observeablecollection into this timer.. and everytime the timer elapsed, it'll add/remove/replace the observable collection

Comment: @GrantWinney i believe i only need to access it within the class.. but i'm not sure as i'm still halfway through this project.  i figure that shouldn't matter tho?

Comment: well the observablecollection is actually a list of IPs.. and the timer will be checking IPs from a network and adding or removing.  i honestly just wanted to do something like _oldObsvCollection = newOBsvCollection in the elapsed Timer.. at the moment i feel it's easier to just replace the whole list.  so i think it just needs access within the class and that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily pass in a callback method:

```
   class Program
   {
      static private CustomTimerClass _customTimer;
      static private int _varIWantToChange = 1;
      static public void Main()
      {
         _customTimer = new CustomTimerClass(changeVar);
         while (_varIWantToChange == 1)
         {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
         }
      }

      static public void changeVar(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
         _varIWantToChange++;
         Console.WriteLine(_varIWantToChange);
      }
   }

   public class CustomTimerClass
   {
      private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
      public CustomTimerClass()
      {
      }

      public CustomTimerClass(ElapsedEventHandler callbackMethod)
      {
         _timer = new Timer();
         _timer.Elapsed += callbackMethod;  //i can't pass varIwantToChange as a parameter here
         _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
         _timer.Interval = 500;
         _timer.Start();
      }

      public void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
         // Do timer stuff
      }
   }
```

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm missing something but that's not accomplishing what i need to do?  please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I modified the code a bit to make it an actual working example.

Comment: The var starts at 1 and then the main thread loops until the var is changed.  At half a second, the timer goes off and the var gets changed to 2, causing the program to end.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a busy wait, from the UI thread no less, while waiting for an asynchronous operation to finish.  You should be letting the UI thread move on to continue processing UI events and doing whatever needs to be done when the asynchronous operation finishes in the callback

Comment: @Servy Agreed, but this is just an example of how to pass in a callback method.  It isn't meant to be a good program.

Answer (score 1):

create a public int property

make your property set _varIWantToChange and get _varIWantToChange if you need it

Comment: you can even set your private int _varIWantToChange = 1; 
to public  int _varIWantToChange = 1;

but, for encapsulation is not recomended doing it, but, once the property is public you can acces it from anywhere : 
Program._varIWantToChange = newValue

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you are not using System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer? The Threading version has constructors that allow you to pass an object in the constructor that is then passed to the handler as an argument.

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx